# $MKLROOT not defined (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intel, environment, intel-mkl

Environment : Linux, Ubuntu 16.04

I tried to download MKL Library from intel website (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/math-kernel-library.html), and try to link mkl to my program.

(I just downloaded `l_mkl_2020.1.217.tar` file, extracted it, and ran `./install.sh` inside that file)

But every time I tried to build, below message was printed

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp.pc

Variable 'MKLROOT' not defined in 'mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp.pc
```

Even if I tried `export MKLROOT=/opt/intel/mkl` (which is my mkl root path), 
It still couldn't find `MKLROOT` path

I also tried run test.sh file like below,

```
echo $MKLROOT
```

and It clearly print `MKLROOT` variable out.

are variable in intel .pc file is somewhat different from environment variable on Ubuntu? and why my mkl couldn't reach out to `MKLROOT` variable?

If anyone can answer this, I'll truly appreciate for you. Thanks!

--- addition ---

I just resolved this issue by adding single line

`MKLROOT=/opt/intel/mkl`

at the very first part of `mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp.pc` (even though its readonly file, I just typed `wq!`), but I think its not a radical solution. Still need answer and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does `sh -c 'echo $MKLROOT'` also prints the variable? Did you do `export MKLROOT=/opt/intel/mkl` without the spaces around `=`?

Comment: It also prints the variable clearly. I typed them without space on my ubuntu console. but Thanks for concern!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `pkg-config` metadata file does not work with external environment variables, even if you properly exported them.

But `pkg-config` has another mechanism for this. You can set `PKG_CONFIG_MKL_DYNAMIC_LP64_IOMP_MKLROOT`:

```bash
$ echo $MKLROOT
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl

$ pkg-config --cflags mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp
Variable 'MKLROOT' not defined in '/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/bin/pkgconfig/mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp.pc'

$ export PKG_CONFIG_MKL_DYNAMIC_LP64_IOMP_MKLROOT=$MKLROOT

$ pkg-config --cflags mkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp
-I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/include
```

In general, the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_XXX_VVV` will override the variable `VVV` in the package `XXX`. Both `XXX` and `VVV` must be in upper case, and with non-alphanumeric characters converted to underscores. (See `man pkg-config`)

(Note that your package is `imkl-dynamic-lp64-iomp`, without the `.pc` extension.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the problem. To set the proper environment variable, you have to call script ( mklvars.sh) to set this environment variable. E.x.source mklvars.sh ia32/intel64 or source compilervars.sh ia32/intel64 in the case if you use an intel compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a script called `mklvars.sh` under the `<mkl_install_dir>/mkl/bin/` directory that sets all the necessary environment variables (like MKLROOT) for you. (I believe you will need to do this each time you want to use MKL, or you can add this to your `./bashrc` file so it gets sourced each time you open your shell.)

With regard to setting the pkg-config files, here are the instructions from the [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-and-pkg-config-tool.html):

> To adjust compilation and link options in the pkg-config metadata file:
>
> 1. Go to the <mkl_install_dir>/mkl/bin/pkgconfig directory.
> 2. Specify the ${prefix} variable,  which contains the full path to the Intel MKL directory that could be changed if another path to MKL is needed.
> 3. Specify Libs:the link line that is returned by pkg_config --libs. You can get the preferred link line for the Intel MKL configuration using the Intel MKL Link Line Advisor  or the offline Intel MKL link line tool. In the link line returned by the advisor, be sure that you change the external environment variable ${MKLROOT} to the internal pkg-config ${prefix}, since the pkg-config metadata file will not work with the external environment variable. However you can set it outside with the pkg-config tool (see the pkg-config tool man page for more information).
> 4. Specify Cflags: the compiler options that will be returned by pkg-config --cflags. You can also update it (see the instruction from step 3).

The Intel MKL Link Line Advisor is available [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html).

In my case, it sufficed to do steps 1 and 2; the link lines and include directories are correct. You might need to change this if you plan to use MKL with the GNU compilers.